# Why does my predictor in two-way fixed effects models have opposite signs in the full panel data vs. period time subsets?

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model, simpsons-paradox

I have a heavily unbalanced panel data set in which certain entities are missing on the DV in certain years. On this data set, I run the two-way fixed effects model: `Y = X +` entity dummies`+`year dummies, where `Y` is the continuous DV and `X` is a time-variant predictor. The coefficient estimate for `X` is **negative** and significant.

Now here's the strange part. If I divide the data into three periods (call them early, middle, and late) and then run the same model on each of these subsets (with the same fixed effects), the coefficient estimate for `X` is **positive** and significant each time.

Is this some kind of Simpson's Paradox? I thought it shouldn't be possible because the entity fixed effects make the model a "within" estimator.